# Moving logs from one server

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, logs, web-app-server

I have a 3 tier farm, 1 WFE, 1 App and 1 DB. The app logs are fairly large so am wanting to move them onto another drive.

Is it possible to move the logs to the app server but keep the WFE logs where they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In** Central Administration > Monitoring > Reporting > Configure Digonistic logging

[image]

You can easily change the trace log path

[image]

**But you should be aware of:**

- This Path for all Sharepoint servers in the farm.
- The specified location must exist on all servers in the farm.

**So, unfortunately,** you can't change the **Trace log path** for a specific server like the application server and keep it for other server cross the farm.

Answer (score 1):

**Log File Location**

By default, SharePoint log files are saved to the following location:

```
C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS
```

The LOGS folder contains log files (`.log`), data files (`.txt`), and usage files (`.usage`). The file naming convention for a SharePoint trace log is the server name followed by a date and time stamp. SharePoint trace logs are created at regular intervals and whenever there is an **IISRESET**. It is common to have many trace logs within a 24 hour period.

[Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/power-pivot-sharepoint/configure-and-view-sharepoint-and-diagnostic-logging)